# Adding text to UITextField you can't delete

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

What I would like to do is to add some text at the beginning of `UITextField` that cannot be deleted. I add this text when the user taps on `UITextField` like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    if (textField.text.length == 0) {
        textField.text = @"myText";
    }

    return YES;
}
```

How do I prevent the user from deleting this text in a normal way? (*without* adding a separate `UILabel` on top of the TextField, for example).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You dont want to delete once you add any text to the text field right?  if Yes.... do userInteractionEnables=NO.. thats it.

Comment: @VSN - I think he only wants to disable part of the text from being editable.  Therefore, he needs to hook into the text changed decision making process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement this code in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField.text.length == 1 && [string isEqualToString:@""]) {//When detect backspace when have one character. 
        textField.text = @"myText";
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout shouldChangeCharactersInRange in the [UITextFieldProtocolReference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

> the text field calls this method whenever the user types a new
>   character in the text field or deletes an existing character.

So, you have control on whether text actually gets changed so you can insert your custom logic in that delegate callback enforcing whatever rules about what can change.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
  - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([[textField text] length]==LENGTH_OF_TEXT && [string isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        return NO;
    }
else 
return YES;
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: No need to, sir, @mani answer works already! Thanks for your effort anyway!