# How Can I restrict the prefix textfield string in iOS?

Tags: ios, delegates, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

How Can I restrict the prefix of `textField` string.

I want the effect that textfield have default prefix string(AAAA-).

(AAAA- after user add string)

And user can't delete these string, user can add the append the string to the `textField`.

How can I use below  delegate method achieve the effect?

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
 {

 }
```

I don't want custom the modal view to achieve these effect.

Have some textfield method can achieve?

thank you

--- detail explain question ---

I use the UIAlertAction add the textfield in AlertAction like below:

at the interface I declare

```
NSString *_prefixString;
```

in the viewdidload set the initvalue

```
_prefixString = @"AAAA-";
```

And I had set the UITextFieldDelegate in header file.

Then the alertviewcontroller set below:

```
    UIAlertController *changeDeviceNameDialog =[UIAlertController
                                             alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"change_device_name",nil)  message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

         UIAlertAction *cancelChangeDevNameAc = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"cancel",nil) style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
         UIAlertAction *enterChangeDevNameAc = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"enter",nil) style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

        UITextField *newDeviceNameTF = changeDeviceNameDialog.textFields[0];
      }];

    [changeDeviceNameDialog addAction:cancelChangeDevNameAc];
    [changeDeviceNameDialog addAction:enterChangeDevNameAc];
    [changeDeviceNameDialog addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField){
        textField.delegate = self;
        textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"new_device_name", nil);
        textField.text = _prefixString;
        }];
       [self presentViewController:changeDeviceNameDialog animated:YES completion:nil];

// below refer the replay

     -(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
     {
      if ([textField.text isEqualToString:_prefixString] && range.location == _prefixString.length - 1 && range.length == 1) {
              return NO;
         }
      return YES;
     }
```

I want the effect is when the alert pop, the textfield have the default text AAAA-,and the user can't clear the AAAA- text.

User just can enter other text append the AAAA-.

But the delegate like upper, I still can remove the prefix text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding text to UITextField you can't delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103453/adding-text-to-uitextfield-you-cant-delete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

Set your `prefixString`,

```
self.prefixString = @"PREFIX";
```

Then in `delegate` method,

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

  if ([textField.text isEqualToString:_prefixString] && range.location == _prefixString.length - 1 && range.length == 1) {

      return NO;
  }

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: if ([textField.text isEqualToString:_prefixString] && range.location == _prefixString.length - 1 && range.length == 1) {
        textField.text = @"AAAA-"
        return NO;
    }
The method still can press delete key to remote prefix string.@@ I want to always show AAAA-, user can add string to AAAA-whatever . can't AAAAxxx.

Comment: @dickfala Why are you setting textField text inside delegate? For me its working as you said.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the replacementString is -1, and it's the range of the string you want to prevent to be deleted, then return FALSE.

Comment: Is these ? if( string.length < 4 )
    {
        return false;
    }
But I try these code, it still can delete.thank you

Comment: Not exactly, `replacementString` should give you the single string that the user has pressed in the keyboard. So, `if(string.length < 0) {return false;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieved what you want by setting `textField` and `setLeftViewMode` as per bellowed code.

```
UILabel *lblPrifix = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
lblPrifix.text = @"AAAA-";
[_textField setLeftView:poundLabel];
[_ textField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Hi, I use UIAlertController. So I can't Add the UILabel in UIAlertController. you can refer my question  after my edit. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let currentText = textView.text as NSString
    let updatedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
    if updatedText.hasPrefix("prefix") {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```